# Map score values to pixels of range [0,255]

Tags: python, image, image-processing, pixel

I want to map the score values which is in range [-1,1] to pixels in range [0,255]. Can we do that, do we have any method for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return int number bettween [0, 255]:

```
mapped_value = round(((x+1) / 2) * 255), 0)
```

If float is acceptable:

```
mapped_value = ((x+1) / 2) * 255
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map it by using math. In the example below, `x` is the value in range [-1, 1].

```
mapped_value = ((x+1) / 2) * 255
```

`x+1` takes the range to [0, 2]. The division by 2 takes the range to [0, 1]. Then we multiply by 255 to take the range to [0, 255].

Answer (score 0):

Scale the value:

```
mapped_value = (x+1) * 127
```